# How to display "ContentType" name in search results?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

I have a MOSS site where I have created custom content types and activated those on a document library.  Now I want to use a custom XSL stylesheet with search results to pull back those documents and display the name of the custom content type assigned for each one.

I know how to create managed properties and map those, etc... but can not seem to find the built-in type that would have the name I assigned to the custom content types?  You would think this would be simple - but simply using a built-in one like "ContentType" returns something generic and not the name of the custom type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The default content type managed property is mapped to multiple crawled properties, with the first one usually being the mime type. I think there is a way to get all values of a property rather than just the first one in the search results xsl, but if that doesn't work out you can always add a custom managed property that only maps to the one crawled property.